# How can I get form values in hook_user_update?

Tags: 8, users

```
function custom_user_update($account) {
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id());
  $level = user->get('field_account_participation')->entity->tid->value;
}
```

Now I need to check my `$level` equals the post value of `field_account_participation`.
How we can do this in Drupal8?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Work out if the value has changed?

Comment: Actually we don't have the option to collect the data for $form_state in hook_user_update, so i have tried in a different way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the documentation of [hook_entity_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_update) one could use $entity->original:

> Get the original entity object from $entity->original.

So you could use this object to find out if your field value has changed by writing something like this:

```
function custom_user_update($account) {
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id());
  $original_value = $account->original->get('field_account_participation')->entity->tid->value;
  $updated_value = $user->get('field_account_participation')->entity->tid->value;

  if ($original_value != $updated_value) {
    // Do something here...
  }
}
```